# How to autoscale elastic search using VPA in kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

Hi I am new to elastic search.

I searched a lot but not found documentation / article regarding auto scaling `elastic search` using `kubernetes` Vertical Pod Autoscaling.

I need to know whether I can do `VPA` with `elastic search` ?

Comment: What is your k8s version and where are you running it?

Comment: k8s version is : v1.14.10-gke.36 and I am running on GKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official google docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler#limitations_for_vertical_pod_autoscaling) regarding the limitations of the Vertical Pod Autoscaling:

> Vertical Pod autoscaling is not yet ready for use with JVM-based
> workloads due to limited visibility into actual memory usage of the
> workload.

and to the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/setup.html#jvm-version):

> Elasticsearch is built using Java, and requires at least Java 8 in
> order to run. Only Oracle’s Java and the OpenJDK are supported. The
> same JVM version should be used on all Elasticsearch nodes and
> clients.

So I am afraid that combining these two is not a recommended way.